# Retrieving table according to the given date range

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

There is table called "table_name" which have 4 columns

```
id    | salary | emp_id | joining_date
---------------------------------------------
1     | 2900   | ep4354 | 2016-04-15 11:15:18
----------------------------------------------
2     | 3001   | ep7354 | 2016-04-16 07:13:01
----------------------------------------------
3     | 4201   | ep7365 | 2016-04-17 08:19:32
----------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to retrieve table from date 2016-04-16 to 2016-04-17 (ignore time). My query in laravel is-

```
$table = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  date(joining_date)>= '".$from."' AND date(joining_date) <= '".$to."'");
```

Where `$from` and `$to` is variable and say there values are $from =2016-04-16 and $to =2016-04-17. So it should display table with two columns as-

```
id    | salary | emp_id | joining_date
----------------------------------------------
2     | 3001   | ep7354 | 2016-04-16 07:13:01
----------------------------------------------
3     | 4201   | ep7365 | 2016-04-17 08:19:32
```

Query is working fine, Thankful to Ankit Verma who helped me within few minutes just after putting my question. I just edited my question to those who said "Question is not clear" still after getting right answer.

Although I want more better query for the same if you guys have.

Comment: Can you better explain your question, are you just wanting to retrieve a value from the column `start_time` which is a dateTime and format it to only show the date?

Comment: I want to retrieve whole table in the given two dates range, which is stored in start_time column and have format 2016-04-15 11:15:18 while taking input in as date format 2016-04-15. So question is how can I match these two different format of in where (), condition.

Comment: cast colomn start_time to date

Comment: Well, Can you tell me the cast syntax in laravel controller ?

Comment: which Database Connectors you are using?i mean MySql
Postgres
SQLite
SqlServer

Comment: u can use like DATE(date) = $date

Comment: $table = DB::table('TableName')
                ->where(date('start_time'), $from)->get();       where $from is in 2016-04-15 format and start_time is in 2016-04-15 11:15:18 and I think I tried as you told, Can you please answer me now because it's showing error already.

Comment: what is the output of your query?. print your last query

Comment: following error throwing QueryException in Connection.php line 669: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '4230amFri, 15 Apr 2016 10:38:42 +000030_303804UTC' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from table_name where 4230amFri, 15 Apr 2016 10:38:42 +000030_303804UTC = 2016-04-06)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In Laravel, use the following code: $table = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE date(created_at)='".$from."'");

Comment: $table = DB::table('table_name')
                ->where(date('start_time'), $from)->get(); this is my query in laravel which is similar logic to your ,but it not working. following error throwing QueryException in Connection.php line 669:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '4230amFri, 15 Apr 2016 10:38:42 +000030_303804UTC' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `table_name` where `4230amFri, 15 Apr 2016 10:38:42 +000030_303804UTC` = 2016-04-06)

Comment: $table = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  date(start_time)='2016-04-14'"); You can also use like this..

Comment: your answer is very close to my solution but I am still sticking in to pass variable say $a ='2016-04-14' So the Query will be  
$table = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date(start_time)=$a"); which is not working .

Comment: $table = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  date(start_time)='".$a."'");

Answer (score 0):

You can try like in mysql connector

```
DATE(date) = $date
```